# Не удается завершить программу с tkinter

Tags: python, алгоритм, tkinter, library

Хочу на python tkinter сделать типа paint. Но возникает такая ошибка которую я не могу пофиксить, как можно это исправить?

```
    self.image=Image.new("RGB",(200,200),(255,255,255))
    TypeError: function takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Исходный код:

```
import tkinter as tk

from PIL.Image import core as Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageChops
class ImageGenerator:
def __init__(self,parent,posx,posy,*kwargs):
    self.parent = parent
    self.posx = posx
    self.posy = posy
    self.sizex = 200
    self.sizey = 200
    self.b1 = "up"
    self.xold = None
    self.yold = None 
    self.drawing_area=tk.Canvas(self.parent,width=self.sizex,height=self.sizey)
    self.drawing_area.place(x=self.posx,y=self.posy)
    self.drawing_area.bind("<Motion>", self.motion)
    self.drawing_area.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.b1down)
    self.drawing_area.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.b1up)
    self.button=tk.Button(self.parent,text="Done!",width=10,bg='white',command=self.save)
    self.button.place(x=self.sizex/7,y=self.sizey+20)
    self.button1=tk.Button(self.parent,text="Clear!",width=10,bg='white',command=self.clear)
    self.button1.place(x=(self.sizex/7)+80,y=self.sizey+20)

    self.image=Image.new("RGB",(200,200),(255,255,255))
    #self.image = Image.new('RGB', (200,200))
    self.draw=ImageDraw.Draw(self.image)

def save(self):
    filename = "temp.jpg"
    self.image.save(filename)

def clear(self):
    self.drawing_area.delete("all")
    self.image=Image.new("RGB",(200,200),(255,255,255))
    self.draw=ImageDraw.Draw(self.image)

def b1down(self,event):
    self.b1 = "down"

def b1up(self,event):
    self.b1 = "up"
    self.xold = None
    self.yold = None

def motion(self,event):
    if self.b1 == "down":
        if self.xold is not None and self.yold is not None:
            event.widget.create_line(self.xold,self.yold,event.x,event.y,smooth='true',width=3,fill='blue')
            self.draw.line(((self.xold,self.yold),(event.x,event.y)),(0,128,0),width=3)

    self.xold = event.x
    self.yold = event.y

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        root=tk.Tk()
        root.wm_geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (400, 400, 10, 10))
        root.config(bg='white')
        ImageGenerator(root,10,10)
        root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш код работает, так же как и код **Victor says Reinstate Monica**.
Ваша ошибка состоит в этом импорте

```
from PIL.Image import core as Image
```

Замените на:

```
from PIL import Image
```